# is it possible to convert protobuf data to json in angular 2 version

Tags: angular2-services

Need to convert row protobuf data into JSON object like mentioned in image using angular 2 only.
I have content type for service call header is

```
'Content-Type': 'application/protobuf'
```

Need to create conversion for following scenario

```
      return this.httpClient. Get(this.IndexUrl,true)
     .then(data => 
      return data; // here i need to convert protobuf to json
```